# order of quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1)$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

I want to find order of quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1)\rangle$,
Since the ideal is not prime. This is not integral domain.
I am stuck.
Similar problem is asked here, but to find order of $R/I$.
This is different question.
I feel order is infinity, but I cannot conclude

Comment: Isn't order=size here? if not, explain. What are $R$ and $I$ in the second part?

Comment: If you mean size, the size will be infinite.

Comment: The quotient will still contain a copy of $\Bbb Z$ so will be infinite.

Comment: Use the chinese remainder theorem to find the structure of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(fg) = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(f) \times \mathbb{Z}[x]/(g)$ if $f$ and $g$ are coprime. If you only want the order in the sense of cardinality, just consider the image of $\mathbb{Z}$ inside your set.

Comment: Are you sure the question was not asking about the quotient ring $$\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+x+1,x^3+x+1)?$$

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that with the ideal of two generators we are left with a ring of three elements, making the question more interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1)\rangle$, and consider $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n\not=m$ as elements of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. We have $n \not \equiv m \mod (x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1)$ since otherwise $n-m \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ would be a non-zero multiple of $(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1)$, and as such would have a higher degree in $x$.

This means that all elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ are different in $R$, so the cardinality of $R$ must be at least that of $\mathbb{Z}$, in other words the cardinality of $R$ is infinite.